# pymongo db.collection.update operationFailure

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a large collection of documents which I'm trying to update using the [pymongo.update](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.6/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) function. I am finding all documents that fall within a certain polygon and updating all the
points found with "update_value".

```
for element in geomShapeCollection:
    db.collectionName.update({"coordinates":{"$geoWithin":{"$geometry":element["geometry_part"]}}}, {"$set":{"Update_key": update_value}}, multi = True, timeout=False)
```

For smaller collections this command works as expected. In the largest dataset
the command works for 70-80% of the data and then throws the error:

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: cursor id '428737620678732339' not
>   valid at server

The pymongo documentation tells me that this is possibly due to a timeout issue.

> Cursors in MongoDB can timeout on the server if they’ve been open for
>   a long time without any operations being performed on them.

Reading through the pymongo documentation, the [find() function](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.6/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) has a boolean flag for timeout.

```
find(spec=None, fields=None, skip=0, limit=0, timeout=True, snapshot=False, tailable=False, _sock=None, _must_use_master=False,_is_command=False)
```

However the [update function](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.6/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) appears not to have this:

```
update(spec, document, upsert=False, manipulate=False, safe=False, multi=False)
```

Is there any way to set this timeout flag for the update function? Is there any way I can change this so that I do not get this OperationFailure error? Am I correct in assuming this is an timeout error as pymongo [states that it throws this error when](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html#pymongo.errors.OperationFailure)

> Raised when a database operation fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research and lots of experimentation I found that it was the outer loop cursor that was causing the error.

```
for element in geomShapeCollection:
```

geomShapeCollection is a cursor to a mongodb collection. There are several elements in geoShapeCollection where large amounts of elements fall, because these updates take such a considerable amount of time the geomShapeCollection cursor closes.

The problem was not with the update function at all. Adding a (timeout=False) to the outer cursor solves this problem.

```
for element in db.geomShapeCollectionName.find(timeout=False):
    db.collectionName.update({"coordinates":{"$geoWithin":{"$geometry":element["geometry_part"]}}}, {"$set":{"Update_key": update_value}}, multi = True, timeout=False)
```